# Instagram Carousel Images Expire

Tags: carousel, instagram, instagram-api

With single image posts, Instagram started expiring image urls. The solution was to use https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/ which will always send update image link for a post.

But with Carousel posts, Instagram only sends first image back.

Que:
1. Does image links in a Carousel post expires?
2. If yes, then how to get new image links for all images in a Carousel?